# "Invalid hook call." when trying to use useState in an arrow function

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-hooks, arrow-functions

Hello fellow StackOverflow community :
I'm encountering this issue, where my react-native app with TailwindCSS and TypeScript is returning me-

```
Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reacts.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
```

I am very new to react-native, trying to build a simple dynamic ui with TailwindCSS and TypeScript as you can see in the following code :

```
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 *
 * @format
 */

import React, {useState} from 'react';
import Svg, {LinearGradient, Stop, Path} from 'react-native-svg';
import type {PropsWithChildren} from 'react';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  ScrollView,
  StatusBar,
  Text,
  useColorScheme,
  View,
} from 'react-native';

type SectionProps = PropsWithChildren<{
  title: string;
}>;

const Cloudy = (props: any) => (
  <Svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 48 48" {...props}>
    <LinearGradient
      id="a"
      x1={6.221}
      x2={37.408}
      y1={5.221}
      y2={36.408}
      gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <Stop offset={0} stopColor="#fed100" />
      <Stop offset={1} stopColor="#e36001" />
    </LinearGradient>
    <Path
      fill="url(#a)"
      d="M24 4C13.507 4 5 12.507 5 23s8.507 19 19 19 19-8.507 19-19S34.493 4 24 4z"
    />
    <Path
      d="M38.998 23.485c-2.403-4.882-11.494-4.479-13.366 2.137-7.157.25-7.769 12.23-.632 12.107h10.995a18.946 18.946 0 0 0 6.927-13.289c-.724-.664-2.596-1.221-3.924-.955z"
      opacity={0.05}
    />
    <Path
      d="M38.925 23.674c-2.594-4.861-11.378-4.165-13.075 2.081-6.67.22-7.012 11.007-.351 11.064.89.008 7.525 0 11.405 0a18.474 18.474 0 0 0 5.999-12.14c-.846-.731-2.606-1.254-3.978-1.005z"
      opacity={0.07}
    />
    <Path
      d="M38.852 23.863c-2.786-4.841-11.263-3.852-12.783 2.025-6.183.19-6.254 9.968-.069 10.022.923.008 8.491 0 11.815 0a18.344 18.344 0 0 0 5.071-10.99c-.97-.799-2.619-1.289-4.034-1.057z"
      opacity={0.07}
    />
    <LinearGradient
      id="b"
      x1={29.373}
      x2={37.64}
      y1={20.668}
      y2={39.146}
      gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <Stop offset={0} stopColor="#fcfcfc" />
      <Stop offset={1} stopColor="#c3c9cd" />
    </LinearGradient>
    <Path
      fill="url(#b)"
      d="M39.5 24c-.245 0-.484.022-.721.053A6.99 6.99 0 0 0 33 21a7 7 0 0 0-6.712 5.021C23.904 26.134 22 28.087 22 30.5a4.5 4.5 0 0 0 4.5 4.5h13a5.5 5.5 0 1 0 0-11z"
    />
  </Svg>
);
const [temperatureLevel, setTemperatureLevel] = useState('');
const temperatureEvaluation = (temperature: any) => {
  if (temperature < 19) {
    setTemperatureLevel('bg-blue-600 rounded-xl');
    return temperature;
  } else if (19 <= temperature && temperature < 27) {
    setTemperatureLevel('bg-green-600 rounded-xl');
    return temperature;
  } else if (27 <= temperature && temperature < 40) {
    setTemperatureLevel('bg-yellow-600 rounded-xl');
    return temperature;
  } else if (40 <= temperature) {
    setTemperatureLevel('bg-red-600 rounded-xl');
    return temperature;
  }
};
function Location(): JSX.Element {
  const isDarkMode = useColorScheme() === 'dark';
  return (
    <View className="flex-col justify-center items-center">
      <Text
        className="text-[10vw] font-medium -mt-[2.5vw] mb-[2.5vw]"
        style={isDarkMode ? {color: '#e5e5e5'} : {color: '#262626'}}>
        Cannes
      </Text>
      <View className={temperatureLevel}>
        <Text className="text-[5vw] text-neutral-200 font-medium px-[2vw] py-[1vw] overflow-hidden drop-temperature rounded-temperature">
          {temperatureEvaluation(15)}℃
        </Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

function Section(): JSX.Element {
  const isDarkMode = useColorScheme() === 'dark';

  return (
    <View className="w-screen h-screen m-auto flex-col justify-center item-center">
      <View className="absolute top-0 flex justify-center items-center left-0 right-0">
        <Text
          className="font-semibold text-[5vw]"
          style={isDarkMode ? {color: '#e5e5e5'} : {color: '#262626'}}>
          Rainy
        </Text>
      </View>
      <Cloudy className="h-[30vw]" />
      <Location />
    </View>
  );
}

function App(): JSX.Element {
  const isDarkMode = useColorScheme() === 'dark';
  const backgroundStyle = 'bg-neutral-200 dark:bg-black';

  return (
    <SafeAreaView className={backgroundStyle}>
      <StatusBar
        barStyle={isDarkMode ? 'light-content' : 'dark-content'}
        backgroundColor={backgroundStyle}
      />
      <ScrollView
        contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior="automatic"
        className={backgroundStyle}>
        <Section />
      </ScrollView>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

export default App;
```

(Here is also a screenshot from the app if that might help) :
[image: Screenshot from the application on iOS]

I've met an error before that was saying "Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop." that I managed to solve by creating the `temperatureEvaluation` arrow function, which then let me use it only on call, but this new error then popped in, and I don't understand it at all.

Does anyone have a clue on how to solve this please ?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message tells you what the problem is.

> Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.

It's hard to spot, because your code is clustered together, but immediately after the definition of your `Cloudy` component you have:

> ```
> const [temperatureLevel, setTemperatureLevel] = useState('');
> ```

… followed by a lot of other code that looks like it is supposed to be part of a component just sitting at the top level of your module (i.e. not inside any function and therefore not part of any component).

Comment: Thank you a lot Quentin ! This solution did work, thank you for your time and efforts.

Answer (score 1):

Hooks must be used in the component Like :

```js
const MyFunction = ()=>{
const [state,setState]=useState()

return (
...
)
}
```

Comment: While this is true, I can't see anywhere in the OP's code where they *aren't* doing that already. Where, precisely, have they gone wrong?

Comment: @Quentin
Check  temperatureLevel state please, it called under Cloudy Component

Comment: That's what you should have said in the answer in the first place.

Comment: Yeah It was my first time Sorry ;)